# Activity does not call onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-activity

the program doesnt call onActivityResult, ive been in many post as this but i cant make it work.

Im using Android 3.0 Emulator.

this is the code of GameScreen.java

```
@Override 
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {      
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
  switch(requestCode) { 
    case 0: { 
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {    
          String newText = data.getStringExtra("isRunning");          
          // TODO Update your TextView.
          isRunning = true;
      } 
      break; 
    } 
  } 
}
 public void pause(){
    clickListener = new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pauseafter);
            isRunning = false;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Gamescreen.this, Shop.class);                  
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    };
}
```

this is the code Shop.java

```
public void returnButton(){
    resume.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: try getIntent() instead of new Intent(). maybe it will work

Comment: well, it did not work `Intent intent = getIntent();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test I've created simple application. Nothing fancy, just default layout and two activities. Toast in `onActivityResult` is shown properly.

Here's complete working code:

file `OnReturnActivity.java`:

```
package some.package;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OnReturnActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, GimmeReturn.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Got Result " + String.valueOf(resultCode),     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

file `GimmeReturn.java`:

```
package some.package;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GimmeReturn extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Returning!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**Both activities need to be added to Android manifest**. Activity `OnReturnActivity` has action MAIN and category LAUNCHER (and is started as main activity for application). Activity `GimmeResult` is just added without any IntentFilter.

Comment: should i use this for both class `setContentView(R.layout.main);`?

Comment: Thanks man for the sample. my Problem was i have `Intent intent = new Intent();` if i thought correctly in my shop.java.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use "RESULT_OK"..
Like this

```
Intent i=new Intent();
 setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
 finish();
```

in OnActivityResult:

```
switch(requestcode)
{
case 0:  if(resultcode==RESULT_OK)
     {

          //Log.e("check","in OAR");
          } 
}
```

Comment: What is the difference? I see some flavor difference, sure, but nothing that jumps out as why @christian 's code doesn't work? :curious:

Comment: it doesn't work. do i have to call onActivityResult in a class/method?

Comment: is it simple activity or Tabhost?

Comment: @Abhi simple activity. i just want it to go to the next activity when the pause button is pressed and return to the previous activity when resume button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems me Ok is your `onActivityResult` never calls or just don't go on case 0: have u tried to debug it. there nothing seems me unusual

Comment: i think it never calls, i tried making an output outside the switch case but it never shows up.

Comment: have u debugged it place debug point in onResume and onActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

Use setData from called Activity.

Comment: setData sets the data from called Activity that can be retrieved from onActivityResult in calling Activity.Make sure you have entered called activity in the AndroidManifest.xml.